# Does sample size needs to be consider in the correlation between a proportion and a ranked variable?

Tags: correlation, proportion, assumptions, spearman-rho

I'm looking for the correlation between a `rank` variable A and the `proportion` of blue (variable B) among 3 types of colour: blue, red, yellow. The Spearman correlation is feasible here since the proportions are independent and their sum is not 1. But the sample size in each rank of var A is quite different, can I directly use the proportion of blue in each rank without weighting on the sum? Or it does not matter if Spearman correlation is applied? How should I weight the sample size if that is an issue for such correlation?

```
var A       blue   red   yellow   sum     
 0           11     0     3        14
 1           9      0     2        11        
 2           3      0     3        6
 3           2      1     0        3
 4           3      0     2        5
 5           1      0     3        4
```

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps more to the point, the blue proportion (or count) is fairly well correlated with the sum.  Is there some reason for this?  If so, it might make more sense to treat blue as a count variable, because the main effect you are seeing is a change in the number of blue things.  (Non-blue things are consistently 1, 2, or 3). You could still use correlation, or regression. Another approach answering your original question, I could see using logistic regression where the dependent variable is blue/not-blue and there are 43 observations.

Comment: `sum` has a correlation with var A, so that the `blue` looks correlate with `sum`, as I'm predicting if the proportion of `blue` is positively correlated with var A, and the combined proportion of `red` + `yellow` is negatively correlated with var A. What is the issue here if I test the correlation on the proportions, rather than count? Thanks!!!

Comment: There's no issue with looking at the correlation with the proportion.  And you have to understand I have zero idea about what your data represents, so I have no idea what would make sense in the real world for your situation.  But for the data you presented, it appears that the main effect is not a shift in the proportion of color, but a change in the number of blue things.  How you want to look at this is up to you and the specifics of your data.

Comment: I thought there was a technical issue on the assumption of proportion test. Thanks